# Open circuit voltage gain of JFET transistor circuit

Tags: voltage, transistors, circuit-analysis

[image]

So this is one of the questions from my previous past papers, I worked out my Vgs and Vds value correctly (-1.25v and 10v). However, when calculating my open circuit voltage gain, I use the equation Av=-gm.Rd, and get the value -25. When I asked my tutor if this was correct, he said that the voltage gain was wrong. He said because there's no capacitor, I need to use the equation Av=-gm.rf/(1+gm.rs) (I assume he meant -gm.rs?) he hasn't elaborated further. Any help would be really appreciated :D (Also ignore the transfer and output characteristic)

Comment: Note that Rs provides negative feedback.  As Id increases, Vgs decreases by Id*Rs.  So what does that do to your gain?  Can you write the equations taking that into account?

Comment: Why is \$A_v = -g_m R_d\$?

Comment: The cap goes across Rs to allow full   Vgs AC swing to get the full gain to the drain. When gm*Rs >>1 your gain without the cap is the R ratio = -Rd/Rs.  Note that the text is old and we use capital S for Siemens now. so remember to use 10 ms  instead of 10mS

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the AC small signal model of a MOSFET, you will see this:

[image]

Therefore, you need to convert your MOSFET circuit into this form and analyze it. **Beware of memorizing and thinking with formulas. This is circuit analysis, not circuit memorization.**

First since this is AC, we can just short out the capacitors so \$V_G=V_{in}\$ and \$V_D=V_{out}\$ (Assuming capacitors are big enough). Then, we can just ignore the \$R_G\$ as it is huge making it essentially an open circuit in the system. We can also ground the \$+V_{DD}\$ DC source as we are looking at this in AC domain. So now gate of the MOSFET goes directly to \$V_{in}\$, drain goes to the ground through RD and source again goes to ground through RS as you can see below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMSw8y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, onto the analysis:

We are trying to find $$A_v=\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}=\frac{V_{GS}}{V_{in}}\frac{V_{out}}{V_{GS}}$$

> For \$\frac{V_{GS}}{V_{in}}\$, \$V_{in}=V_G\$ and \$V_S=g_mV_{GS}R_S\$. So \$V_{GS}=V_G-V_S=V_{in}-g_mV_{GS}R_S\$. Therefore, \$\frac{V_{GS}}{V_{in}}=\frac{1}{1+g_mR_S}\$.

This is our first expression.

> For \$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{GS}}\$, since all the current, \$g_mV_{GS}\$, is flowing through \$R_D\$, \$V_{out}=-g_mV_{GS}R_D\$. So \$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{GS}}=-g_mR_D\$

This is our second expression.

Finally, if we put both expressions into \$A_v\$,

$$A_v=\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}=\frac{-g_mR_D}{1+g_mR_S}$$.

When you plug in these, the answer you get is -4.17 V/V. As you can see with this, \$R_S\$ provides negative feedback into this amplifier, lowering the gain.